# Perl: Given the year and week number, how can I get the first date in that week?

Tags: perl, datetime

Using the excellent Perl [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) module it is trivial to obtain the year and week number for a date, but going the other way seems to be a bit more difficult.   How does one go about obtaining a date starting with the year and week number?

Comment: What other modules did you try?

Answer (score 14):

Here's one way to do it using only [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime):

```
use DateTime;

sub first_day_of_week
{
  my ($year, $week) = @_;

  # Week 1 is defined as the one containing January 4:
  DateTime
    ->new( year => $year, month => 1, day => 4 )
    ->add( weeks => ($week - 1) )
    ->truncate( to => 'week' );
} # end first_day_of_week


# Find first day of second week of 2012 (2012-01-09):
my $d = first_day_of_week(2012, 2);

print "$d\n";
```

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
use Date::Calc qw(:all);

my $year = 2012;
my $week = 14;
my ($year2, $month, $day) = Monday_of_Week($week, $year);
```

Comment: That is simpler than my DateTime version, but if you're already using DateTime, you probably don't want to pull in Date::Calc just for this.  It's not _that_ hard to do with DateTime.

Comment: Thanks both of you.  I don't mind adding Date::Calc to the modules list.  I take it that Date::Calc follows the same "fourth day of January" ISO rule as DateTime on this.  Oh heck.  I'll go RTFM. :-)  Thanks again.